# LINQ inserts data but it doesn't stay saved in database LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have tried to insert data into database using LINQ, but I've come across a problem. Basically my code runs without errors, but when I check database no new instances were inserted although while program is running some kind of "local copy" does the job, I believe. Here is my code and I will insert the pictures to show you what happens when I run it and what when I check the database.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Parents_LINQ.Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString);

        if (textBox1.Text!="" && textBox2.Text != "" && textBox3.Text != "" && textBox4.Text != "" )
            if(radioButton1.Checked || radioButton2.Checked || radioButton3.Checked)
        {
                using (DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext(con))
                {
                    ParentTbl newParent = new ParentTbl();
                    newParent.ParentID = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

                    if (radioButton1.Checked) 
                        newParent.TypeID = 1;
                    else if (radioButton2.Checked) 
                        newParent.TypeID = 2;
                    else if (radioButton3.Checked) 
                        newParent.TypeID = 3;

                    newParent.Name = textBox2.Text;
                    newParent.Lastname = textBox3.Text;
                    newParent.Adress = textBox4.Text;
                    newParent.Phone = maskedTextBox1.Text;
                    newParent.MobilePhone = maskedTextBox2.Text;

                    dc.ParentTbls.InsertOnSubmit(newParent);

                    try 
                    {
                        dc.SubmitChanges();
                        MessageBox.Show("You have successfully inserted new parent: " + textBox2.Text + " " + textBox3.Text);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Name, Lastname and Address must be given!");
        }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwuyB.png)

Clicking on the button new it shows the next value that can be inserted into database as if the instance was inserted, but checking database, there is no change to be seen:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Fpie.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0roB3.png)

Comment: Can you please show us the **connection string** you're using for your SQL Server database?

Comment: make sure you are inserting records in the same DB in which you are checking the records

Comment: Since your Database1.mdf is included in your project, you need to make sure it is not set to be copied to the output folder every time you build your project.